# 301 status code cause rewrites to be redirect

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-rewrites

I'm try to setup rewrites to deal with CORS issue

but the destination with status code 301 caused the client to fetch from the destination
nextjs version 12.2.3

```
  async rewrites() {
    return [
 
      {
        source: "/google-image/",
        destination:
          "https://serpapi.com/search.json?engine=google_images&q=Coffee&location=Austin%2C+TX%2C+Texas%2C+United+States&google_domain=google.com&gl=us&hl=en&api_key={mykey}",
      },
    ];
  },
```

[image]

[image]